# How to detect if a paragraph is a list paragraph or not

Tags: vba, ms-word

For example, using WORD VBA, how can we determine if last paragraph of a document is a ListParagraph (list item) or just a simple plain paragraph:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Last
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
If ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Last.Style = "List Paragraph" Then...
```

Comment: Doesn't always work because the list can be set to a different style.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know and want to check each of the the list paragraph styles in your document, I would suggest:

```
If Not(ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range.ListFormat.List is Nothing) Then
```